# No logro obtener los equipos de la red de área local

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema, el programa no muestra los equipos que se encuentran en la red de área local, yo digo que está bien, no veo errores en el programa pero no logro encontrar el por qué pasa eso, les dejo el programa:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Muestreo 
public partial class Network : Form
{
    public Network()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Dll Imports
    [DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    public static extern int NetServerEnum(
        string ServerNane,
        int dwLevel,
        ref IntPtr pBuf,
        int dwPrefMaxLen,
        out int dwEntriesRead,
        out int dwTotalEntries,
        int dwServerType,
        string domain,
        out int dwResumeHandle
        );
    [DllImport("Netapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(
        IntPtr pBuf);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _SERVER_INFO_100
    {
        internal int sv100_platform_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string sv100_name;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public ArrayList getNetworkComputers()
    {
        ArrayList networkComputers = new ArrayList();
        const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
        int SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION = 1;
        int SV_TYPE_SERVER = 2;
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tmpBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        int entriesRead = 0;
        int totalEntries = 0;
        int resHandle = 0;
        int sizeofINFO = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(_SERVER_INFO_100));
        try
        {
            int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries, SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, null, out resHandle);
            if (ret == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalEntries; i++)
                {
                    tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((int)buffer + (i * sizeofINFO));

                    _SERVER_INFO_100 svrInfo = (_SERVER_INFO_100)
                        Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer, typeof(_SERVER_INFO_100));
                    networkComputers.Add(svrInfo.sv100_name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problema con el acceso a las computadoras de la red en el explorador de red " +
                "\r\n\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message,
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
        }
        return networkComputers;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Aquí mando a llamar el método:

```
private void button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Muestreo.Network nb = new Muestreo.Network();
    foreach (string pc in nb.getNetworkComputers())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(pc);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Resolviste el problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Tu código funciona correctamente, creo que el problema se debe a la API que estás usando: en la descripción de **[NetServerEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa370623(v=vs.85).aspx)** en la página de MSDN indica "enlista todos los servidores de un tipo específico que están visibles en un **dominio**".

En mi caso funcionó correctamente listando las computadoras unidas al dominio, sin embargo deja fuera otros dispositivos como teléfono móviles, impresoras, equipos Linux, switches, etc.

Para enlistar dichos equipos puedes hacer un ping a todos las ip en el segmento de direcciones que te encuentras como en el siguiente ejemplo:

`
        private int hostsEncontrados = 0;

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            hostsEncontrados = 0;

            string address;

            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 10000;
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
            int intentos = 254;

            for (int i = 1; i <= intentos; i++)
            {
                Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(pingCompleted);

                address = "192.168.1." + i.ToString();

                pingSender.SendAsync(address, timeout, buffer, options);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message; 
        }finally
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }

    private void pingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            PingReply pr = e.Reply;
            if (pr.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                string hostname = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                    ip = pr.Address.ToString();
                    hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(pr.Address).HostName; //<-- Comentar esta línea de código para ejecutar rápidamente sin resolver nombres
                    hostsEncontrados++;
                }
                finally
                {                
                    listBox1.Items.Add(hostname + " (" + ip + ") tiempo=" + pr.RoundtripTime);
                    label1.Text = hostsEncontrados.ToString() + "  host encontrados.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(ip + " // " + ex.Message);                
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

¿Si lo colocas en una clase?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace MachineScanner
{
    public class clsMachineScanner
    {
        #region Dll Imports
        [DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    public static extern int NetServerEnum(
        string ServerNane,
        int dwLevel,
        ref IntPtr pBuf,
        int dwPrefMaxLen,
        out int dwEntriesRead,
        out int dwTotalEntries,
        int dwServerType,
        string domain,
        out int dwResumeHandle
        );
    [DllImport("Netapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(
        IntPtr pBuf);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _SERVER_INFO_100
    {
        internal int sv100_platform_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string sv100_name;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public ArrayList getNetworkComputers()
    {
        ArrayList networkComputers = new ArrayList();
        const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
        int SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION = 1;
        int SV_TYPE_SERVER = 2;
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tmpBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        int entriesRead = 0;
        int totalEntries = 0;
        int resHandle = 0;
        int sizeofINFO = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(_SERVER_INFO_100));
        try
        {
            int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries, SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, null, out resHandle);
            if (ret == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalEntries; i++)
                {
                    tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((int)buffer + (i * sizeofINFO));

                    _SERVER_INFO_100 svrInfo = (_SERVER_INFO_100)
                        Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer, typeof(_SERVER_INFO_100));
                    networkComputers.Add(svrInfo.sv100_name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
        }
        return networkComputers;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Y luego llamalo desde un boton:

```
private void btnScanear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsMachineScanner nb = new clsMachineScanner();
        ArrayList lista =  nb.getNetworkComputers();
        foreach (string pc in lista)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: si en la misma clase realice todo no se si eso influyo

Comment: Es una buena practica que los las llamadas a dlls externas las realices en otra clase.